# libgcc_s_dw2.dll is missing when running executeable file on different machine

Tags: gcc, exe

I am running executable from different and I get this error (program can not find libcc_s_dw2.dll).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `libgcc_s_dw2.dll` ist part of MinGW runtime.

You have 2 ways to fix this:

1. Copy `libgcc_s_dw2.dll` into your program's folder (where the exe is) or your system `PATH`
2. Compile the program with `-static-libgcc` (and `-static-libstdc++` if C++) flag.

If you choose 1., and you don't have the file: You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/gcc-4.7.2-1/) (`libgcc-4.7.2-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.lzma`).

This is for *MinGW GCC 4.7.2*, for other versions of this file you have to browse the website a bit. So if your application crashes, you have to look for another (= correct) version. Best you check what GCC Version has been used before.